# Migrating my localhost website to BlueHost

Tags: php, wordpress, web, localhost, shared-hosting

This is my first time to doing this kinda project. The scenario is that I am trying to migrate my localhost WordPress website to Bluehost. I've encountered some errors that my website is not going live and if I enter my website address my old WordPress website is appearing. Steps I used:

1. Export database from phpMyAdmin to .sql file. (I used notepad)
2. Import my website folder into Bluehost.
3. Create database into Bluehost cPanel and assign a userid.
4. Import database .sql (notepad) file into phpMyAdmin of Bluehost. (when I was uploading .sql notepad file I was getting an error which has been fixed by using -- in the beginning of the database script).
5. change the database path of wp-config using the database name and password I have set up in Bluehost.

My domain is still with WordPress, I did not transfer it to Bluehost, is that the reason my website address still showing the old WordPress site? or I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace old website address with new website address.

Means when you export the local/old website .sql file. please open the old sql file and find the old website URL and replace this URL with new website URL.

For example you old website url is http://localhost/wordpress_site and new website URL is http://new_website.com

Then you need to find localhost/wordpress_site in your exported sql file and replace with xyz.com and import into new database.

Comment: Thank you vishal for your reply. Yes I updated/change the local host address to the new website address. ex http://localhost/wordpress_site to the new website http://new_website.com in the database. Secondly, When I export .sql file instead of showing localhost it was showing ex 127.0..0.1 ip address. it it normal or do I have to change it to localhost?

Comment: You need to replace your ip/site_foldername address to your domain

Answer (score 1):

The domain will tell the internet where your website is located, more specific it's A record will forward to a specific IP address.

To get your website 'live' on a different host you need to either edit the domain settings (called DNS management) or transfer the domain to the new location.

Alternatively you can tell your own computer (windows/mac/Linux) to NOT look at the global DNS, but instead manually refer to the IP adres of bluehost. That way you can test drive your website. For windows you will need an entry in the c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file.

Comment: That's what I was thinking that I need to transfer my domain to bluehost. I will try it tonight. Thanks!